# DocuSign / Salesforce integration - tags not appearing with template

Tags: templates, tags, salesforce, docusignapi

I have a custom button in SalesForce to use the "One Click Option" Send Now feature. The button also specifies to use a template with tags already in it.

If I login to DocuSign and preview the document as the signer would see it, I can see the tags.

However, when I send a request from SalesForce using the Send Now feature, the tags are not visible when the signer views the documents. I know that the sender can tag the fields in SalesForce, but that seems to defeat the purpose of having a template with the tags already present.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Here is the custom button code below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES=''; 
//*************************************************//


// One Click Option (default edit envelope screen)
OCO = 'Send'; //Ex: Tag 
CRL = 'Email~{!New_Hire_Checklist__c.Correspondence_Email__c};FirstName~{!New_Hire_Checklist__c.First_Name__c};LastName~{!New_Hire_Checklist__c.Last_Name__c};Role~Applicant'
DST = '6005ADE1-54B2-4215-B060-C15E5821A695'

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!New_Hire_Checklist__c.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES; 
//*******************************************//
```

Comment: Usually when you send a template to a recipient (from in Salesforce or outside) if the tabs don't show up for them that means the the recipient has not been matched with a template role.  Are you positive that the template you are sending has a role called `Applicant` and that your recipient is getting set to that role?

Comment: Hi Ergin. You are correct. That was exactly the problem. I had not added an additional parameter (CCRL) to define the role. Thank you.

Comment: Great, can you please accept my answer in that case?  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem, lines 9 and 10 of your code are missing ending semi-colons `;`.  Try changing to this:

```
CRL = 'Email~{!New_Hire_Checklist__c.Correspondence_Email__c};FirstName~{!New_Hire_Checklist__c.First_Name__c};LastName~{!New_Hire_Checklist__c.Last_Name__c};Role~Applicant';
DST = '6005ADE1-54B2-4215-B060-C15E5821A695';
```

Notice the semi-colons added at the end of each line.